# How to loop on Array from mySQL in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

The data that's returned from my MySQL database is an array in this format (in this example it's about languages):

```
var arrayLang = ["French","English"];
```

But I can't use `map` or `forEach` to get each value as it says `arrayLang.map is not a function`. I tried `arrayLang[1]`, but it's value is `[`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried outputting what `arrayLang` is to see?

Comment: Does `Array.isArray(arrayLang)` return `true`? If it doesn't, then it's not an array. Have you tried `Array.from(arrayLang)`? If it splits everything in that array into individual strings, when you use `Array.from`, it is a string.

Comment: you may need to do `JSON.parse(arrayLang)`

Comment: A JSON.parse done the work , thanks for y'all

Answer (score 0):

your arrayLang is probably a `string`.

`var arrayLang = '["French","English"]';`

use `arrayLang = JSON.parse(arrayLang)` to start using it like an array